# How do I load Json encode into a variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a page "jsonencode.php" containing encoded arrays

```
[["Easth1","North1","A","URL1"],["Easth2","North2","B","URL2"]]
```

I know I can load in html in to a div with:

```
$("#div").load("jsonencode.php");
```

but I want to do is load arrays into a variable like:

```
var a = load("jsonencode.php");
```

Comment: The possibility to `await` an operation safely is [under consideration for the language](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262#current-proposals). In the meantime, synchronous I/O is generally to be avoided in JavaScript as it halts the execution of your entire application while it waits. This makes for a terrible user experience. Avoiding that requires you, as the developer, to accept alternate techniques for writing your application – using callbacks, promises, etc. Related: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.getJSON('jsonencode.php', function(obj) {
    //obj not holds your parsed JSON as a JS object
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/